# How to check inserting row on duplicity based on multiple attributes?

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlalchemy

I'm working in `SQLAlchemy`. Is it possible to set `equality` of two rows so if the row is being inserted and there exists a row with the same 2 columns already , lets say 'creation_date' and 'destination_from', then the second row wont be inserted?

I don't want to create a `PRIMARY KEY` on those columns.

I suppose that checking manually whether there is already a row with those columns is unefficient.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy import Column
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
import datetime

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///db.db', echo=False)
Base = declarative_base()

s = sqlalchemy.orm.Session(engine)

class Flight(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'flights'
    id = Column(sqlalchemy.Integer, primary_key=True)
    destination_from = Column(sqlalchemy.String)
    destination_to = Column(sqlalchemy.String)
    creation_date = Column(sqlalchemy.Date)
    start_date = Column(sqlalchemy.Date)
    return_date = Column(sqlalchemy.Date)
    price = Column(sqlalchemy.Float)


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

def insert_into_flights(**kwargs):
    s.add(Flight(**kwargs))
    s.commit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to create a PRIMARY KEY, but can't you create a [UNIQUE CONSTRAINT](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#unique-constraint)?

```
UniqueConstraint('creation_date', 'destination_from')
```